# How to update child component after props are changed in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have component TopicsView where I have property called choosenTopicId which I change on button click. Inside this component I have child component

```
<TopicViewOnSide TopicId={this.state.choosenTopicId} />
```

Inside TopicViewOnSide I use TopicId in componentDidMount() when I'm sending request from axios (HTTP GET) to get topic data from the server and then component TopicViewOnSide renders. My problem is when I change choosenTopicId by clicking button in TopicView, props are changed and it's good. But the child component doesn't rerender when the props are changed and I have old topic data because the child component didn't call componentDidMount() and there was no request to server. Can I somehow call the method componentDidMount() when the props are changed so the request from axios will be send and my data will be updated ?

Comment: You're looking for `componentDidUpdate()` which gets triggered after every state or prop change. The `componentDidMount()` method only runs a single-time.

Comment: Is it the only way ? On the start of rendering this component its state changes a lot of time and the method with request is called a lof of time in componentDidUpdate that slows app to the point it can't be used ( lags that much).

Comment: It all depends how you set-up your componentDidUpdate(). You can do something like componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ if(this.props.blaw !== prevProps.blaw){ ...execute your logic } } That creates a check so logic wont execute all the time.

Comment: Oh yes, that worked when I checked condition with prevProps, thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad that worked for you. If you don't mind, I've moved my suggestions to the solution below. Please consider upvoting it and marking it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `componentDidUpdate()` which gets triggered after every state or prop change. The `componentDidMount()` method only runs a single-time.

You can do something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ 
   if(this.props.blaw !== prevProps.blaw){
     ...execute your logic 
   }
}
```

That creates a check to do something only when `props` change.